# Hibernate a home server?

Tags: hibernate, windows-server-2012

I have been learning about setting up a server and have obtained a copy of Server 2012 essentials from school. the idea (while learning about active directory/directory services, groups, security, and the like) is to have the 4 client computers at home share printing service and have regular back ups done and file share to and from the server.

That being said, the server really does not have to be on 24 x 7. Just during hours when people are at home or when the back up task is triggered.

There is no power plan that puts the server into a real power save mode. I understand this from a company perspective and having resources and service available all the time.

My question:

Is there anyway a home user can make the server go to sleep or preferably Hibernate for a period of time until an event trigger wakes it?

All the client rigs are Windows 7 and 8.

Comment: I guess you're looking for Wake on LAN. The event being network activity or a magic packet being sent to the server, which will awaken it. You can configure Windows to automatically sleep or hibernate after a period of inactivity.

Comment: @Vinayak - But on Server 2012, I see not sleep or hib option.

Comment: Does this work? [Enable Standby in Windows 2008 R2 Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/baliles/archive/2010/06/08/tips-amp-tricks-enable-standby-in-windows-2008-r2-server.aspx). I read in the comments that it works for Windows Server 2012 as well.